# nodejs postgresql query returns wrong timestamp

Tags: node.js, postgresql

In my postgresql db, time is stored in UTC with following format:

> 2015-11-04 02:02:16.092375-05

The offset 5 is added based on the server timezone.

When I query that data using pg in nodejs, I get the wrong time:

> Wed Nov 04 2015 07:02:16 GMT+0000 (UTC)

The offset 5 hours is added. The correct time is supposed to be

> Wed Nov 04 2015 02:02:16 GMT+0000 (UTC)

Here is my code for querying data:

```
var queryString = "SELECT timestp FROM TABLE_NAME"
var client = new pg.Client(connString);
client.connect(function(err) {
    var query = client.query(queryString, function(err, result) {
        var time = result.rows[result.rows.length-1].timestp;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why the offset is added to time in UTC and still returned in UTC?

Comment: Is this the same issue as [**Postgres UTC date format & epoch cast, sign inversion**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8399140/479863)?