# Inconsistent time zone conversion in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, timezone, postgresql-10

I'm attempting to select a local time (as at Australia/Brisbane) from a `timestamptz` field in a PostgreSQL database and noticed that when I use the `+10` time zone abbreviation, PostgreSQL appears to subtract 10 hours from the UTC value instead of adding 10 hours.

If I use `AEST` as the abbreviation, 10 hours are correctly added.

When I run the following query I would expect both values returned to be the same.

```
select 
  ('2018-01-01T00:00:00Z'::timestamp with time zone) at time zone 'AEST', 
  ('2018-01-01T00:00:00Z'::timestamp with time zone) at time zone '+10';
```

However, in my case I'm seeing the following results:

```
"2018-01-01 10:00:00"   | "2017-12-31 14:00:00"
```

If I run the following query, all rows have a "utc_offset" interval of 10:00:00.

```
select * from pg_timezone_names
where abbrev in ('+10', 'AEST')
```

Could anyone offer an explanation as to what is going on here?

Comment: I think you;re looking at a duplicate of this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399140/postgres-utc-date-format-epoch-cast-sign-inversion/8399859#8399859

Comment: Why not just pass `at time zone 'Australia/Brisbane'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is actually described in some detail in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES):

> PostgreSQL allows you to specify time zones in three different forms:
>
> - A full time zone name, for example `America/New_York.` [...]
> - A time zone abbreviation, for example `PST`. [...]
> - In addition to the timezone names and abbreviations, PostgreSQL will accept POSIX-style time zone specifications of the form `STDoffset` or `STDoffsetDST`, where `STD` is a zone abbreviation, `offset` is a numeric offset in hours west from UTC, and `DST` is an optional daylight-savings zone abbreviation, assumed to stand for one hour ahead of the given offset. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> Another issue to keep in mind is that in POSIX time zone names, positive offsets are used for locations ***west*** of Greenwich. Everywhere else, PostgreSQL follows the ISO-8601 convention that positive timezone offsets are ***east*** of Greenwich.

So the POSIX equivalent for `AEST` would be `-10` or `UTC-10`.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, after reading the documentation more closely this now makes sense. I had thought that since "+10" was in the "abbrev" field for a number of rows in the pg_timezone_names view that it would be taken from there. I missed the mention of the pg_timezone_abbrevs view and POSIX offsets being west of GMT.