# Why is 'UTC-4" timezone in Postgres leads to +04, and 'UTC+4' leads to -04?

Tags: postgresql, time

To me, it seems more intuitive to have 'UTC-4' associated with '-04' and vice versa.

I attached an image here of what I get when trying to select the current time in the corresponding timezone.

[image]

Comment: What is your local time zone? Btw: the use of `time with time zone` (and thus `current_time`)  is [discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_timetz)

Comment: Please post code as text, not image.

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8399859

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the link in the comment from @a_horse_with_no_name, `UTC-4/UTC+4` are POSIX style time zone designations and as such the direction from `UTC` is reversed. In other words `+` is going west from Greenwich  and `-` is going east. Your choices are:

1. Recognize that and reverse your signs as needed.
2. Use a known timezone say `America/Porto_Velho`(-04) or `Asia/Baku`(+04). Though this offset may change if `DST` rules change for that timezone.
3. Do something like below. I am currently in `PST` in USA:

```
select current_time;
    current_time    
--------------------
 09:05:28.464408-08

 select (split_part((current_time at time zone 'UTC' - interval '4 hours')::varchar, '+', 1) || '-04')::timetz;
       timetz       
--------------------
 13:05:39.056446-04

select (split_part((current_time at time zone 'UTC' + interval '4 hours')::varchar, '+', 1) || '+04')::timetz;
       timetz       
--------------------
 21:05:50.624686+04
```

**UPDATE**

The reference location for the POSIX  time zone explanation has changed to [POSIX timezone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datetime-posix-timezone-specs.html) and is:

> The offset fields specify the hours, and optionally minutes and seconds, difference from UTC. They have the format hh[:mm[:ss]] optionally with a leading sign (+ or -). The positive sign is used for zones west of Greenwich. (Note that this is the opposite of the ISO-8601 sign convention used elsewhere in PostgreSQL.) hh can have one or two digits; mm and ss (if used) must have two.